# Needing VB to read from a txt file or any other file and do a specific action

Tags: vb.net, testing, blocking

So I am building a blocker program for my own family's personal use.

So lets say I have a txt file listing these websites:
www.notarealwebsite.com
www.fake.net

I want it to find the txt file that has that information, then pull it and use it and since my program is a web browser I want it to block those websites I defined.

**I ONLY WANT IT TO BLOCK THE WEBSITE IN MY APPLICATION NOT OVER THE WHOLE COMPUTER** (meaning I don't want it to be  blocked in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"blocked.txt": One site per line.

It's not ready to be used directly, because it can be easily bypassed by entering "somesite.com/" instead of the blocked "somesite.com".

But it should give you the idea.

```
    Dim urlBlocked As Boolean = False ''The ugly way...
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("blocked.txt")
        If TextBox1.Text = line Then
            urlBlocked = True
            MsgBox("Action Blocked!")
        Else
            If Not urlBlocked Then
                WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    urlBlocked = False
End Sub
```

Comment: It's been a while since I have read this. And I have become a more experienced programmer thank you. I have figured it out.              


`Blacklist:
http://blockedwebsite.com/*
http://www.blockedwebsite.com/*
http://blockedwebsite.com
http://www.blockedwebsite.com`